# import angular library with multiple internal projects

Tags: angular, angular8

I have created a library using angular. now I don't want to  upload the library in `npm`. because it's all within the company polices.
in this case, after I build the library how can i share with other applications withing the organization using git repo if require.

I tried to copy and paste the build library, and one of my application, i just add in to the `angular.json` in script part like :

```
"scripts": [
   "./../xyz-library/public-api.d.ts"
]
```

and in app module, it trying to import like this:

```
import { IboLibraryModule } from '../../../xyz-library/ibo-library.d';
```

but getting an error as :

`Cannot find module '@angular/core'`.

any one help me to understand the correct approach or show me the idea to full fill my requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a npm package manually as long as it has a valid `package.json` file. For example if it's on git, they can clone it and then install the package from its file path:

```
git clone https://github.com/example/example-repo.git
```

Then install it from local path instead of npm server:

```
npm install ./example-repo
```

Comment: I did this command: ` yarn add global` it was success. when I try to add with another application, I got the error as `error Command "ibo-library" not found.` how to solve this?

Comment: @user2024080 I can't tell for sure, this might have various reasons...